# Why getting this Error selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, staleelementreferenceexception

I know already upload answer to this same question but I try them they are not working for me because there is also some some update in selenium code too.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.95)
```

When trying to send my searching keyword in this input with label "Skills Search" in advance searching pop-pup form.

**Here is the URL**: https://www.upwork.com/nx/jobs/search/modals/advanced-search?sort=recency&pageTitle=Advanced%20Search&_navType=modal&_modalInfo=%5B%7B%22navType%22%3A%22modal%22,%22title%22%3A%22Advanced%20Search%22,%22modalId%22%3A%221670133126002%22,%22channelName%22%3A%22advanced-search-modal%22%7D%5D

**Here is my code:**

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('F:\\work\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.upwork.com/nx/jobs/search/?sort=recency"
driver.get(url)

key = ["Web Scraping","Selenium WebDriver", "Data Scraping", "selenium", "Web Crawling", "Beautiful Soup", "Scrapy", "Data Extraction", "Automation"]
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler')))
time.sleep(5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))).click()
for i in range(len(key)):
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@title,"Advanced Search")]'))).click()
    time.sleep(5)
    advanced_search_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[contains(@aria-labelledby,"tokenizer-label")]')
    # advanced_search_input.click()
    advanced_search_input.send_keys(key[i])
```

[image]

result giving now [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By clicking `'//input[contains(@aria-labelledby,"tokenizer-label")]'` element it is re-built on the page (really strange approach they built that page).
To make this code working I added a delay after clearing and clicking that input and then get that element again.
The following code worked for me:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.upwork.com/nx/jobs/search/?sort=recency"
driver.get(url)

keys = ["Web Scraping","Selenium WebDriver", "Data Scraping", "selenium", "Web Crawling", "Beautiful Soup", "Scrapy", "Data Extraction", "Automation"]
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler')))
time.sleep(5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))).click()
for i in range(len(keys)):
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@title,"Advanced Search")]'))).click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input[contains(@aria-labelledby,"tokenizer-label")]'))).clear()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[contains(@aria-labelledby,"tokenizer-label")]'))).click()
    time.sleep(3)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[contains(@aria-labelledby,"tokenizer-label")]'))).send_keys(keys[i])
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[data-test="modal-advanced-search-search-btn"]'))).click()
```

**UPD**
In order to select multiple search values you need to insert each value, select the appearing autocomplete option and continue, as in the code below:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.upwork.com/nx/jobs/search/?sort=recency"
driver.get(url)

keys = ["Web Scraping", "Selenium WebDriver", "Data Scraping", "Selenium", "Beautiful Soup", "Scrapy", "Data Extraction", "Automation"] #
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler')))
time.sleep(5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@title,"Advanced Search")]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input[contains(@aria-labelledby,"tokenizer-label")]'))).clear()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[contains(@aria-labelledby,"tokenizer-label")]'))).click()
time.sleep(3)
for i in range(len(keys)):
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[contains(@aria-labelledby,"tokenizer-label")]'))).send_keys(keys[i])
    time.sleep(2)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#typeahead-input-control-35 .up-menu-item-text"))).click()
    time.sleep(4)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[data-test="modal-advanced-search-search-btn"]'))).click()
```

**UPD**
Finally did it!
The problem with wrong inputs caused by too slow response time of that page.
To make it working I inserted a small delay between inserting each character of the input string. In this case the result is as expected.
This is the final working code:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.upwork.com/nx/jobs/search/?sort=recency"
driver.get(url)

keys = ["Web Scraping", "Selenium Webdriver", "Data Scraping", "Selenium", "Beautiful Soup", "Scrapy", "Data Extraction", "Automation"]
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler')))
time.sleep(5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@title,"Advanced Search")]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input[contains(@aria-labelledby,"tokenizer-label")]'))).clear()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[contains(@aria-labelledby,"tokenizer-label")]'))).click()
time.sleep(3)
for i in range(len(keys)):
    search_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[contains(@aria-labelledby,"tokenizer-label")]')))
    search_field.click()
    for character in keys[i]:
        search_field.send_keys(character)
        time.sleep(0.05)
    time.sleep(2)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#typeahead-input-control-35 .up-menu-item-text"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[data-test="modal-advanced-search-search-btn"]'))).click()
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: I update a screenshot I want put keys in this field like this , not one by one

Comment: @InfoRewind have you tried the updated answer?

Comment: Yes I tried but its not putting the the complete keywords from my list , after putting 2 words from my list, it is start putting first latter of word from the list and picking random item from the suggestion

Comment: I attached the image of the result above ,It is not same as I want

Comment: I know. This caused not by my code failures but by that site very strange behavioral. I will try to improve that, had no time during the working day, but this solution is much better than a single JavaScript click you got as an answer previously where you instantly accepted and upvoted the answer...But again, I'll try to improve it now.

Comment: Yes please, thanks in advance , I will wait

Comment: Done. That site is really very bad.

Comment: You are welcome. This was a challenge :)

Comment: I raise a new question can you please help me in that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74699744/why-getting-exception-time-out-error-or-element-not-found-on-this-line-by-css-se

Comment: I see. Today I'm working from the offices, my boss near me and I have a lot of work to do, but if I will have a time I will try to help. I see that code is long, need to debug.

Comment: ok thanks i will wait

Comment: I am still waiting